# testing IE9 on virtual pc

Tags: windows-7, virtual-pc

I've downloaded the windows7 vhd from microsoft's site. I created a virtual pc from that vhd. It runs ok, but the welcome screen want a password for one of the accounts (admin and administrator).

I've tried guessing a few passwords but with no luck...

Anyone knows the correct password?

Comment: Read the `readme` file that came in the download.

Comment: On mine it is: Passw0rd!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11575

> The password to login to all of these images is Password1 and the username will be present when you first login.

Comment: `Passw0rd!` worked for me